# Android: Show always a ProgressBar inside AsynckTask with runOnUIThread

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

There are an application that process many operations in an `AsyncTask` that has a `runOnUIThread` call.
The application has the code to show an indeterminate `ProgressBar` when the process it's doing in background, but the progress bar isn't shown always, in one cases yes, in other cases no.

With this model of (bad structure) code, how can I sure that the progress bar always is shown

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AsyncTestActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private ProgressDialog pd = null;

    private void loadingBar(String titulo){
        pd = ProgressDialog.show(this, titulo, "Please wait ...", true, false);
    }

    private void closeLoading(){
        pd.dismiss();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_async_test);

        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

        Task async = new Task(textView);
        async.execute("");
    }

    private class Task extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        private TextView tv;

        public Task(TextView tv) {
            this.tv = tv;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            loadingBar("Warning");//I want to show this always
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        for(int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
                            Thread.sleep(1000);
                        }
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
            return "End";
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            tv.setText(result);
            closeLoading();
        }
    }
}
```

I, can't change the structure (`AsyncTask/runOnUIThread`)the code because is big and I have few time to do this. The goal is that the progress bar always is ahowed. I had been reading that this is a bad practice, but the code was made by another person.

Comment: You really shouldn't be calling runOnUiThread from an async task, you should use progress updates instead, which is functioanlity already built into AsyncTask..  In fact, if the task is likely to take more than a few seconds you probably shouldn't even use AsyncTask, as it will prevent any other tasks launched from being run until its finished (the system does 1 async task at a time on the same thread unless told otherwise).

Comment: Yeah, I know that. But this code was made by another person. Is many code to fix at this moment (move it). The task right now is "always show the progress bar (loading bar)"

Comment: By "always", do you mean "until the request is finished"?

Comment: first you **have** to manage the `task/request` in your case can do it with this code , if you done what looking for right now its not correct code anyway when `progressBar` showing for user its not mean its work for current task its maybe stuck for another `request`

Comment: Yes, show the bar while the task is running :) when it ends, hide the bar

Answer (score 0):

Call `loadingBar("Warning");` before `async.execute("");`.

---

If it's not showing, there is a problem with your ProgressDialog. Can you try edit loadingBar() method like this? :

```
ProgressDialog pd;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_async_test);

    //init progress
    pd = new ProgressDialog(this);

    //
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

    Task async = new Task(textView);
    async.execute("");
}

private void loadingBar(String titulo){
    pd.show();
    pd.setTitle(titulo);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you ever try to call `bringToFront()` inside your `onPreExecute()`:

```
@Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        loadingBar.bringToFront();
        loadingBar("Warning");//I want to show this always
    }
```

(Untested code)

or if you want to make sure, you can include your progressBar as your `Task` parameter then directly execute `bringToFront()`;

```
public Task(TextView tv, ProgressBar pB) {
            this.tv = tv;
            this.pb = pB.bringToFront();
        }
```

hope it helps

Comment: Doesn't exists a `bringToFront` method.